# C pointer changes without modifying it

Tags: c, pointers

I am getting some weird pointer-related errors that I do not understand how can happen and how to solve it. Since I am new to C any good coding practice advice is also appreciated.

```
typedef struct matrix {
    int n;
    int m;
    int **data;
    int *inverses;
} Matrix;

Matrix m_new(int n, int m, int *inverses) {

    int **data = malloc(n);

    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        int *row = malloc(m + 1);
        *row++ = k;
        *(data+k) = row; 
        // print_arr(*data); - introduced for debugging purposes
    }

    Matrix mat = {
        .n = n,
        .m = m,
        .data = data,
        .inverses = inverses,
    };

    return mat;
}

void print_arr(int *arr) {
    int len = *(arr-1);
    printf("len: %d\n", len);
}
```

Here, I am going to use this matrix for Gaussian Elimination over the integers mod some number, that's why I have the inverses array, and I use `int **`, so that I can swap rows easily later. For arrays represented as `int *` I use the -1th entry to store the length of the array. I got some weird bugs, so I wrote a small function to get the length of an array (print_arr) and check the first array in data. I got the following(for n=m=5):

> len: 0
> len: 0
> len: 0
> len: 0
> len: -1219680380

Which I find really weird, because it seems like that something is changing in the last iteration, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your allocations are too small. You need to multiply the number of elements by the size of the elements to compute how much memory to allocate:

```
int **data = malloc(n * sizeof (int *));

int *row = malloc((m + 1) * sizeof (int));
```

With your current code, you overflow your too-small buffers and cause undefined behavior.